# data iteration in directive for org chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, logic, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEGLHYAdMX1yXi0piHa0?p=preview) which have css based Organization Chart, i am tring to make it dynamic in angular js [plunker_angular js](http://plnkr.co/edit/aGR7kwbTIAaAAdbU4PGD?p=preview), i am new to custom directive,

is there any way to itrate my `$scope.data` with keep in mind it's parentId to draw a organation chart how can i do this using directive  [plunker_angular js](http://plnkr.co/edit/aGR7kwbTIAaAAdbU4PGD?p=preview)

depth of chart can be nth level , any help ?

Comment: Do you already have a data model (json) that represents your tree?

Comment: yes in [script.js](http://plnkr.co/edit/aGR7kwbTIAaAAdbU4PGD?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your actual model, it's not easy to do. You would have to create UL elements on the fly while looping through the data with parentId = null.

I propose you change your data model into a hierarchy of objects like so:

```
[{
  'id':1,
  'name':'Shailendra Sharma',
  'children': [
    {'id':2,'name':'sonu'},
    {'id':3,'name':'Rahul'},
    {'id':4,'name':'sam'},
    {'id':5,'name':'Jhon'}
  ]
}]
```

This way a parent has children and you can nest ng-repeat:

```
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in data">
      <a href="#">{{d.name}}</a>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="c in d.children">
          <a href="#">{{c.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DqEsLJq6gv1BSE1vm3hs?p=preview)

EDIT:

To build an infiite tree, you can just make the directive call itself.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="d in data">
    <a href="#">{{d.name}}</a>
    <hierarchical-view ng-if="d.children" data="d.children"></hierarchical-view>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VxygrP1MxXWAPImOS6Dg?p=preview)

Comment: i want a dynamic directive, your answer will failed for 3rd level , and yes data model can be mold

Comment: @ShailendraSharma you just create another directive that will generate the children http://plnkr.co/edit/Adr3iLY7gbixozZyPiiE?p=preview (there's a minor css issue to fix but you have an infinite tree working)

Comment: you don't even need 2 directives actually. http://plnkr.co/edit/VxygrP1MxXWAPImOS6Dg?p=preview